# Hibernate: Two Foreign key as ids

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have defined a many-to-one relationship between my three entity classes `catalogB`, `tableA` and `tableAB`. `tableAB` has a primary key composite of `tableA.tableAId`  and `catalogB.catalogBId`, and I used the following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableAB", schema = Constantes.SCHEMA_SOLICITUD,uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "tableAId  ", "catalogBId" }) })
public class TableAB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6360131240770014903L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableAId", referencedColumnName = "tableAId")
    private TableAId tableAId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalogBId", referencedColumnName = "catalogBId")
    private CatalogBId catalogBId;
```

And that gives me an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [schema.TableAB ] does not define an IdClass
```

Comment: This code is in SpringBoot with javax.persistence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930935/illegalargumentexception-expecting-idclass-mapping). The accepted answer as well as other answers shed light on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That could help me,but  he dont show the class "AssignedRoleId.class"

Comment: Then refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585034/how-to-map-a-composite-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate). It provides two approaches, `EmbededId` and `IdClass`.